# I am getting $C$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$ in kile

Tags: errors

I am using this header file while writing in kile, but I am getting `$C$` instead of `$\mathbb{C}$`, could anyone tell me whether the below header file is sufficient for writing advanced mathematical article or not? If not it will be great if you give me a full package list. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. thank you very much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amscd}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{epsfig}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{rsfs}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{rsfs}{n}{it}{<-> rsfs10}{}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}

\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}

\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}

\newcommand{\bb}{\mathbb}

\newcommand{\bd}{\textbf}

\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}

\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray}}

\newcommand{\bean}{\begin{eqnarray*}}

\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{equation*}}

\newcommand{\cl}{\mathcal}

\newcommand{\del}{\partial}

\newcommand{\disp}{\displaystyle}

\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}

\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray}}

\newcommand{\eean}{\end{eqnarray*}}

\newcommand{\een}{\end{equation*}}

\newcommand{\f}{\mathfrak}

\newcommand{\imply}{\Rightarrow}

\newcommand{\la}{\left|}

\newcommand{\lr}{\left(}

\newcommand{\ls}{\left[}

\newcommand{\para}{\paragraph}

\newcommand{\pgbrk}{\vspace*{\fill}\pagebreak}

\newcommand{\ra}{\right|}

\newcommand{\rr}{\right)}

\newcommand{\rs}{\right]}

\newcommand{\rta}{\rightarrow}

\newcommand{\xrta}{\xlongrightarrow}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Please don't declare cryptical abbreviations vor environments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has two `\documentclass` lines so will generate an error whatever document follows. Also never use `epsfig` package, use `graphicx`. If you have a problem with `\mathbb` it would have helped if you had provided an example showing that problem. But you need to load `amsfonts` package.

Comment: Thank you, now the \documentclass problem gone and I am getting $\mathbb{C}$, but after compilation I am getting error, I am not expert in this, could you just write the final package for me dear sir? :)

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce "getting an error" isn't helpful. how can we tell you how to fix that if you don't say (exactly) what the error is, copying the lines from the log file. What makes you think the error is on the preamble/package code, not in the document itself? Edit the code in your question to be a complete _small_ document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that generates an error, then someone could tell you how to fix that error.

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce fix your MWE, remove that second `\documentclass` and add some contents to recreate your porblem and finish it with `\end{document`(then you must include a `\begin{document}` also in your code. Otherwise could be very hard to help you dear lady ;)